# Multiple instances of constructor not working

Tags: javascript, debugging, undefined

When I run this program with only one instance of Cat (var cat1), it works perfectly. **When I run a second instance** (var cat2), **things stop working.**

```
function main() {
    var catPic = document.getElementById('catPic');
    var numClicks = 0;
    var numCats = -1;
    var scope;

    var Cat = function Cat(name, url) {
        numCats++;
        scope = this;
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.numClicks = 0;
        this.clickId = 'clicks' + numCats;

        window.onload = function() {

            //Puts a new Cat on the screen. The name, image, and # of clicks will be shown.
            appendCat(scope.name, scope.url, scope.clickId, scope.numClicks, numCats);

        }
    };

    var cat1 = new Cat('Bob', 'https://lh3.ggpht.com/nlI91wYNCrjjNy5f-S3CmVehIBM4cprx-JFWOztLk7vFlhYuFR6YnxcT446AvxYg4Ab7M1Fy0twaOCWYcUk=s0#w=640&h=426');
    var cat2 = new Cat('Samantha', 'https://lh3.ggpht.com/nlI91wYNCrjjNy5f-S3CmVehIBM4cprx-JFWOztLk7vFlhYuFR6YnxcT446AvxYg4Ab7M1Fy0twaOCWYcUk=s0#w=640&h=426');
}

main();
```

The problem has something to with the appendCat(); function.

```
    //Puts a new Cat on the screen. The name, image, and # of clicks will be shown.
    function appendCat(name, url, clickId, numClicks, numCats) {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[numCats].setAttribute('id', 'cat' + numCats);

        document.body.getElementById().appendChild(document.createElement('h2'));
        document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[numCats].textContent = name;

        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[numCats].setAttribute('id', name);
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[numCats].setAttribute('src', url);

        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        document.getElementsByTagName('p')[numCats].setAttribute('id', clickId);
        document.getElementsByTagName('p')[numCats].textContent = numClicks;

        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
```

When these first two lines of this function are run, *document.getElementsByTagName('div')[numCats]* evaluates to undefined. I'm not sure why this happens. Console.log() isn't helping me much either. Thanks!

Comment: Is this the actual code? Not sure how `document.body.getElementById()` would ever run without an error. Separately, kinda weird that you'd put `var scope` in `main()` and not in `function Cat()`. As it is, every new `Cat` will set its `this` as the `scope` for *all* `Cat` objects.

Comment: Its not c++. Why do you use  `window.onload` and `appendCat` in constructor ? And your `scope.numClicks` is always 0.

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the scope variable altogether. I've also moved all of the stuff that shouldn't be in the constructor elsewhere. I'll definitely never make the mistakes I made in this code again thanks to you two (and @Ethan Lynn of course).

Comment: What is document.body.getElementById() ? Not sure how can it run even once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your `scope` variable needs to be declared within the constructor so that `window.onload` is referring to the correct instance. Otherwise, both `window.onload` handlers will refer to whatever value of scope was set to at the time `window.onload` triggers — which will always be the second instance. Second, instead of setting `window.onload`, you need to use `window.addEventListener("load", function () { ... }")` so that each instance has it's own listener. The `window` object only has one `onload` property so setting it multiple times doesn't create multiple listeners it just overwrites the previous ones.

As an additional note, I would suggest removing the event handling from the constructor and placing it outside something like this:

```
var cats = [
    new Cat(...),
    new Cat(...)
];
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    cats.forEach(function (cat) {
        appendCat(cat.name, cat.url, cat.clickId, cat.numClicks, cats.length);
    });
});
```

This would remove the `scope` and `numCats` variables and move all the `window.onload` funtionality to one handler instead of having one handler for each instance.

Comment: Thanks! Lots of facepalming occurred after reading your responce. Also, I ended up using a for() loop instead of forEach (better performance).

Comment: Did you ran his code. Infact I am seeing so many other issues!!